# JQuery Append Data to a html select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Jquery script whic retrieve data from the  Database as json :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "database/Emarps/websrvc/websrvc.php?task=getData&UUID=" + currentuuid + "&DataGt=hk",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response) {
      $('#PrevOptns').val(response[0].hiv_prev);
      $('#HivTrans').val(response[0].hiv_trans);
    }
  });

});
```

How can I pass the data to reflect or be appended  on the  following HTML select tag (The Select tag accepts multiple selection and the  data returned can be more than one for one select )  :

```
<select required name="HivTrans" id="HivTrans" size="7" multiple class="select_with_label_wide">

  <option id="Handshake and close body contact">Handshake and close body contact</option>
  <option id="Mosquito's and other insects">Mosquito's and other insects</option>

  <option id="Kissing">Kissing</option>
  <option id="Sharing of needles/Syringes">Sharing of needles/Syringes</option>
  <option id="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<select required name="PrevOptns" id="PrevOptns" size="7" multiple class="select_with_label_wide">

  <option id="Avoid mosquito bites">Avoid mosquito bites</option>
  <option id="Get protection from traditional healer">Get protection from traditional healer</option>
  <option id="Other">Other</option>
  <option id="Don't know">Don't know</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you post the json response here

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#PrevOptns").append('<option value='+response[0].hiv_prev+'>'+response[0].hiv_prev+'</option>');
    $("#HivTrans").append('<option value='+response[0].hiv_trans+'>'+response[0].hiv_trans+'</option>');
   $('#PrevOptns').trigger("chosen:updated");
   $('#HivTrans').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append all the data, try to do 'for each' cycle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "database/Emarps/websrvc/websrvc.php?task=getData&UUID=" + currentuuid + "&DataGt=hk",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response) {
      for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
         $('#PrevOptns').append('<option value='+response[i].hiv_prev+'>'+response[i].hiv_prev+'</option>');;
         $('#HivTrans').append('<option value='+response[i].hiv_trans+'>'+response[i].hiv_trans+'</option>');
      }
    }
   });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has an [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method that you can use to insert content to the end of html elements. Build up your  elements and simply append them to the relevant select tag.

**JS**

```
success: function (response) {
    var prevOpts =  "<option value='" +response[0].hiv_prev +"'</option>";
    var hivTrans=  "<option value='" +response[0].hiv_prev +"'</option>";

    $("#PrevOptns").append(prevOpts);
    $("#HivTrans").append(hivTrans);

}
```